# Can I use batch to rename a file keeping the old file exstension in the name

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I am trying to find a way to mass move a file from from cd to desktop.  Then take the name and extension and mass combine, while adding a new extension. 
Example of what I am trying to change.

```
12.001
12.002
12.003
13.001
13.002
13.003
```

Goal

```
12.001.tif
12.002.tif
12.003.tif
13.001.tif
13.002.tif
13.003.tif
```

or

```
12001.tif
12002.tif
12003.tif
13001.tif
13002.tif
13003.tif
```

I am trying not to loose the file count or association that is why I am keeping 001 002 003 if I dont I will not be able to tell what file goes with which group.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a one-liner from the command prompt (no batch file needed). This will put it in the first format you specified above (`12.001.tif`):

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %A IN (`DIR E: /B /S`) DO COPY /V "%A" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Files\%~nxA.tif"
```

Replace `E:` with the path to your source files and adjust `%UserProfile%\Desktop\Files\` to the appropriate location to copy the files.